# How to access window.BinanceChain object like window.ethereum object on page load

Tags: web3js, web3-providers, ethers.js

I am trying to initiate provider from the `window.BinanceChain` object injected by **Binance Wallet** chrome extension as I did it with the **MetaMask** extension before:

```
let provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
```

But I have noticed that on page load I have initiated `window.ethereum` object, but undefined `window.BinanceChain` object:

```
console.log(window.ethereum)
console.log(window.BinanceChain)
```

The result is:

[image]

What is the proper way to initiate **Binance Smart Chain** provider on page load?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I noted that window.BinanceChain object is not available as early as window.ethereum, so you need to wait for it. My solution was to add an additional state check:

```
   document.onreadystatechange = () => {
     if (document.readyState == "complete") {
       window.web3 = new Web3(window.BinanceChain);
       // do stuff
     }
   }
```

Tip: you can check if the object is available after the page is loaded by typing console.log(window.BinanceChain); inside the browser's developer tools in the console to see if it gets initialized at some point at all?